# Android Baseadapter TextEdit not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, baseadapter

I have a weird problems for some days and I really hope to find help here.

I have a ListView using Baseadapter and so customized cells. My cells own a ImageView and EditText.

I want the user to enter a comment on the EditText and upload an image if he desires. But now the problem: If I want to upload the cells to the server I can't get anything. I can't read the information in TextEdit field and I don't know why this happens.

Here's my code of my baseadapter:

```
package com.example.other;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.decidenow.R;
import com.example.item.AnswerItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class AnswerItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
protected List<AnswerItem> listCars;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AnswerItemAdapter(Context context, List<AnswerItem> listCars ) {
    this.listCars = listCars;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listCars.size();
}

public AnswerItem getItem(int position) {
    return listCars.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return listCars.get(position).getID();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final AnswerItem car = listCars.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_poll_item,
                parent, false);

        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.answer = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_answer);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    car.setAnswer(holder.answer);
    car.setImageView(holder.imageview);

    holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            Activity origin = (Activity) context;
            origin.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "uploading image"), car.getID());
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    EditText answer;
}
}
```

My custom cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layout_answer"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_comment"
    android:background="@color/main"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/answer_box"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ecf0f1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/item_answer"
    android:hint="@string/answer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="3.34">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:src="@drawable/insert_photo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:maxHeight="80dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

AnswerItem to store the cells:

```
package com.example.item;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AnswerItem {
private EditText answer;
private ImageView view;
private int ID;

public AnswerItem(int i) {
    ID = i;
}

public void setID(int i) {
    ID = i;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public ImageView getImageView() {
    return view;
}

public EditText getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public void setImageView(ImageView v) {
    view = v;
}

public void setAnswer(EditText a) {
    answer = a;
}

}
```

And those are some parts of my main class (activity):

```
...
ListView list_poll_item;
AnswerItemAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<AnswerItem> arrayPolls = new ArrayList<>();
list_poll_item   = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_answer);
list_poll_item.setAdapter(adapter);
...
arrayPolls.get(i).getAnswer().getText().toString()
```

And no, I don't get any errors. I just get an empty EditText String.

I really hope you can help me this problem is very annoying.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** **UPDATE**

My adapter looks now like this:

```
package com.example.other;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.decidenow.R;
import com.example.item.AnswerItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class AnswerItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
protected List<AnswerItem> listCars;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AnswerItemAdapter(Context context, List<AnswerItem> listCars ) {
    this.listCars = listCars;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listCars.size();
}

public AnswerItem getItem(int position) {
    return listCars.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return listCars.get(position).getID();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)             {
    final AnswerItem car = listCars.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_poll_item,
                parent, false);

        holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        holder.answer = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.item_answer);

        holder.myTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher(holder.answer);
        holder.answer.addTextChangedListener(holder.myTextWatcher);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.answer.setText(car.getComment());
    holder.myTextWatcher.setCar(car);

    car.setImageView(holder.imageview);

    holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            Activity origin = (Activity) context;
            origin.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "uploading image"), car.getID());
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    EditText answer;
    ImageView imageview;
    MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher;
}

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private AnswerItem car;
    private EditText mEditText;

    public MyTextWatcher(EditText mEditText) {
        this.mEditText = mEditText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (car != null) {
            car.setComment(mEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    public void setCar(AnswerItem car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot see where you use `EditText.getString()`?

Comment: It's the very last line: arrayPolls.get(i).getAnswer().getText().toString() @hoomi

Comment: Can you at least share when/how `arrayPolls.get(i).getAnswer().getText().toString()` is being called?

Comment: yes: for (int i = 0; i < arrayPolls.size(); i++) {
                    query += "{\"comment\":\"" + arrayPolls.get(i).getAnswer().getText().toString() + "\",\"imagebase64\":\"" + base64 + "\"},";
                }

Comment: I leave you an answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you assume that you have an `EditText` for each row. This is an incorrect assumption. You probably only have 4-5 `EditText` instances which have the same value for all of your rows.

What you need to probably do is in your `AnswerItem` add another field and methods :

```
private String comment;
public String getComment(){
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    return this.comment = comment;
}
```

Then this in your `getView()`:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_poll_item,
                    parent, false);

            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            holder.answer = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_answer);

            holder.myTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher(holder.answer);
            holder.answer.addTextChangedListener(holder.myTextWatcher);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // The order needs to be exactly this way because setText will call
        // AfterTextChanged on the previous row
        holder.myTextWatcher.setCar(car);
        holder.answer.setText(car.getComment());

        car.setImageView(holder.imageview);

        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                Activity origin = (Activity) context;
                origin.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "uploading image"), car.getID());
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here are the other classes that you need :

```
private class ViewHolder {
        EditText answer;
        ImageView imageView;
        MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher;
    }

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private Car car;
    private EditText mEditText;

    public MyTextWatcher(EditText mEditText) {
        this.mEditText = mEditText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (car != null) {
            car.setComment(mEditText.getText());
        }
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
}
```

Comment: **THANK YOU VERY MUCH @hoomi** :-) It works fine so far but when I refresh after adding a new object to the list my text disappears... Update: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: sorry that I've realized this later... could u help me here too?

Comment: Ok let me take a look at it.

Comment: I think I know what happens. When you add a new object is your list being refreshed? What I mean is you `List<Car>` is that being replaced? I am guessing the field comment is not being persisted. Can you confirm that?

Comment: No, it's not replaced. I add it like this:
 `arrayPolls.add(new AnswerItem(size));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Can you update your answer with the new modifications? It is a bit hard to picture how your adapter looks

Comment: Can you please check to see if when `holder.answer.setText(car.getComment());`  is being executed `car.getComment()` does actually return a value and it is not empty String or null.

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't understand what u mean. But I noticed one more thing: If I scroll down and back the text which I've entered vanishes too... So I think it's not executed. @hoomi

Comment: I think I identified the bug. It was with the order of  `holder.myTextWatcher.setCar(car);` and `holder.answer.setText(car.getComment());`. Swap them around and the bug should be fixed.

Comment: Oww thanks! @hoomi But I kind of have problems with my images. They don't appear on the ImageView but are loaded to the server. Is this bug related to this adapter or somewhere else?

Comment: That is because you are not setting the `ImageView` drawable/btimap

Comment: Thanks so much @hoomi

Comment: Can you raise that as a different issue? And send me the link.